# Does alcohol worsen the symptoms of benign prostate enlargement?

Tags: alcohol, prostate

Googling suggests that men suffering from benign prostate enlargement are advised not to drink alcohol or caffeine containing beverages, but I have also found research articles suggesting that alcohol has no effect on benign prostate enlargement. Is there an accepted view on this?

I would guess one possible confusion is whether we are talking about long term or immediate effects. For example a long term effect would be whether alcohol consumption makes the benign prostate enlargement gradually worse over time. A short term effect would be be whether drinking alcohol causes temporary difficulty urinating, and this eases as the alcohol is metabolised. Likewise caffeine consumption. It would be useful if anyone answering could treat long and short term effects separately.